# Error for oneOf validation on swagger without using oneOf

Tags: python, api, flask, swagger

I try to make a very simple API in flask with swagger, my swagger.yaml file is really not complex and don't use any oneOf or ref, but still get an error about refs and oneOf, I'm not familiar with swagger so I assume that I'm doing something wrong but can't find what.

there is my swagger config:

```
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: Swagger Template
  description: A Template API
  version: "0.1"

paths:
  /analyse_coordonates:
    get:
      operationId: app.core.analyse_coords
      summary: Endpoint to receive coordonates and return bivouac zone
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: e
        schema:
          type: string
        description: E coordonate
      - in: query
        name: n
        schema:
          type: string
        description: N coordonate
      produces:
      - text/plain
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: integer
```

there is the error:

```
[2022-07-20 09:51:40 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/back_end/run.py", line 6, in <module>
    APP = flask.create_app()
  File "/back_end/app/flask/__init__.py", line 15, in create_app
    app.add_api("swagger.yaml", strict_validation=True, validate_responses=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apps/flask_app.py", line 65, in add_api
    api = super().add_api(specification, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apps/abstract.py", line 149, in add_api
    api = self.api_cls(specification,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/apis/abstract.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.specification = Specification.load(specification, arguments=arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 152, in load
    return cls.from_file(spec, arguments=arguments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 106, in from_file
    return cls.from_dict(spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 143, in from_dict
    return Swagger2Specification(spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 37, in __init__
    self._validate_spec(raw_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/connexion/spec.py", line 215, in _validate_spec
    raise InvalidSpecification.create_from(e)
connexion.exceptions.InvalidSpecification: {'in': 'query', 'name': 'e', 'schema': {'type': 'string'}, 'description': 'E coordonate'} is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['paths']['patternProperties']['^/']['properties']['get']['properties']['parameters']['items']:
    {'oneOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/parameter'},
               {'$ref': '#/definitions/jsonReference'}]}

On instance['paths']['/analyse_coordonates']['get']['parameters'][0]:
    {'description': 'E coordonate',
     'in': 'query',
     'name': 'e',
     'schema': {'type': 'string'}}
[2022-07-20 09:51:40 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI the word is "coordinates"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like problem is here:

```yaml
      - in: query
        name: e
        schema:
          type: string
        description: E coordonate
```

this way of specifying type of param is allowed in OpenAPI 3, but not in Swagger (OpenAPI 2)

In Swagger, the `schema: type:` form is only allowed for "body" params, not querystring.

See:

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/ (OpenAPI 3)
- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-parameters/ (Swagger)

To fix it just change your schema to:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"

info:
  title: Swagger Template
  description: A Template API
  version: "0.1"

paths:
  /analyse_coordonates:
    get:
      operationId: app.core.analyse_coords
      summary: Endpoint to receive coordonates and return bivouac zone
      parameters:
      - in: query
        name: e
        type: string
        description: E coordonate
      - in: query
        name: n
        type: string
        description: N coordonate
      produces:
      - text/plain
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: integer
```